# Page Progressbar

Tags: jquery, html, css

My client wants to have a progressbar on initial page load. And the instant the page loads to hide it.
So I thought about it and come up with this.

```
var num = 0,
    progress = $('.progressbar'),
    interval = setInterval(function(){
        num++
        progress.text(num+'%')
    }, 100);

$(window).load(function(){
    clearInterval(interval);
    $({number: num}).animate({number: 100}, { 
      duration: 1000,
      easing:'swing', 
      step: function() { 
          progress.text(Math.round(this.number)+"%");
      }
    })
})
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6sJ9c/) (I added a large image to show the loading)

The only thing I can come up in order to decrease the chance of the number reaching 100 before the `dom load` is to add a few `if` to check if the num is for example 50% and decrease the interval repeating value, and the same thing on 75% I guess, but I don't find it very smart.

So pretty much my question is - "Is there a smarter way to do this?"

Comment: Maybe this can help you? http://www.inwebson.com/jquery/jpreloader-a-preloading-screen-to-preload-images/

Comment: I get that this was a client request but the better question here should be: how do I avoid having to put a progress bar in it? Progress bars and spinners are not great UX. A good approach might be to be optimistic about the layout and already display it alongside everything you can display instantly and then fill network-intensive things into the already existing layout when they are available. However if you are at all interested in this you might want to take it over to ux.stackexchange

Comment: @Ingo Bürk when it comes to clients we have no power... He say he wants a kitty - I put a kitty, if he wants the navigation to be a table, I make it a table, if he wants IE6 support I support it... No power at all :)

Comment: @drip Yeah, but some clients appreciate suggestions (they can still say no). You certainly know your client better, though, so it was just a little suggestion. :)

Comment: by the way... this plugin may help:http://usablica.github.io/progress.js/

Comment: #2 http://www.graphicdesignblender.com/rediculous-client-requests-and-how-to-reason-with-them

I'd use @IngoBürk's comment about progress bars and spinners not being UX-friendly as justification for saying no. That and moving it to ux.stackexchange for the sake of strengthening your argument. Remember that you're building the site, not the client, which means you're the one with the advantage and, therefore, the power. "Quite frankly, I'd rather have a few people hate me deeply than apply
 stuff I don't like." -- Linus Torvalds

Comment: Just a comment from an amateur user and minimalist programmer - "The person who signs the check has the power". :-) ;-)}

Comment: Really, it depends on your kind of job. As a consultant our customer relies on us deciding implementation details, they just decide on the features. But a web designer might have either a customer saying "do it like this, basta" or "build me a nice website". Hence me saying: OP knows their customer best. You can't force OP or the customer and the OP doesn't feel comfortable making such suggestions, so I'm sure they have their reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea, I'm sure you've considered the jQuery progress bar.

I found this concept on [Code Academy](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-ia4mc/0/1) and made this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/k3vuu/).

JS

```
var mybar = $(".progressbar").progressbar({value: 1});

var progress = setInterval(function() {
                                       updateprog();
                                       }, 10
                          );

function updateprog ()
{
      var currentVal = $(".progressbar").progressbar("option", "value");
       var nextVal = currentVal + 1;
       if (nextVal > 100)
          {
           $(mybar).hide();
           clearInterval(progress);
           } else
          {
           $(".progressbar").progressbar({value: nextVal});
           }
}
```

I haven't styled anything, but that should be fairly straight-forward.